# rails_admin Handling Ancestry Category Trees

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-admin

I'm evaluating **rails_admin** but am coming up against a problem with our use of the **ancestry** gem. In an admin context the default rails_admin simply displays the ancestry key as a text value (which is not that useful).

What would be better would be the ability to view the ancestry (up and down) for a given category in the show view, and to be able to select a new parent in the edit view (i've managed to create the dropdown, but not the control to preselect the current parent if there is one).

Have you come across this problem and do you have any ideas how to get round it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this plugin using jquery nestable: https://github.com/dalpo/rails_admin_nestable

[image: rails_admin_nestable]

For more details see the github [readme](https://github.com/dalpo/rails_admin_nestable/#rails-admin-nestable).

Comment: Could you give at least an overview of how you went about solving the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have proper rendering of hierarchies with https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree. Haven't tried ancestry with it though.

Give it a try and let us know

[image: list of hierarchy]
[image: edit screen]

Comment: So, I know this is a year and a half later, but I'm trying to implement a similar structure using both Closure Tree and Rails Admin. How did you get the the child list to work like it does?